# $_POST arrays building new array from foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, post, foreach

I have a some values in my $_POST that are in there own arrays similar to this,

```
array(
   ['conviction_date'] = array(
      [0] => 12/01/2011
      [1] => 22/12/2011
   )
   ['conviction_description'] = array(
      [0] => This some text to show what the conviction was for etc.
      [1] => This is some more text to show what the second convication was for
   )
)
```

What I want to know is how do I loop through said arrays so that I can value from one to the match the value of the other via there keys?

Is it as simple as this,

```
foreach ($_POST['conviction_date'] as $k => $v) {
    $newArray[] = array(
       'conviction_date' => $v,
       'conviction_details' => $_POST['conviction_details'][$k]
    )
}
```

Will this then output something to the following?

```
array(
    [0] => array(
      'conviction_date' => 12/01/2011
      'conviction_details' => This is some to show what the conviction was for etc.
    ),
    [1] => array()
      'conviction_date' => 22/11/2011
      'conviction_details' => This is some more text to show what the second convication was for
    )
```

Is there away to build a simpler array?

Comment: You are mismatching spelling of "conviction" and "convication" (which isn't a real word) all over the place. And so begins the spaghetti...

Answer (score 1):

Edit the form to the following might be simpler:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="conviction_date[]">
<input type="text" name="conviction_details[]">
</form>

if (isset($_POST) { var_dump($_POST); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be simpler to give the parameters names so that php will create an array like

```
array( 'conviction'=>array(
  0=>array('date'=..., 'details'=>...),
  1=>array('date'=..., 'details'=>...),
  ...
);
```

Then you can do something like

```
foreach( $_POST['conviction'] as $c ) {
    echo $c['date'], ' ', $c['details'], "\n";
}
```

A simple demo form:

```
<form method="post" action="...">
    <fieldset><legend>0</legend>
        <input type="text" name="conviction[0][date]">
        <input type="text" name="conviction[0][details]">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset><legend>1</legend>
        <input type="text" name="conviction[1][date]">
        <input type="text" name="conviction[1][details]">
    </fieldset>
    ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample has a few errors, e.g. conviction date: 12/01/2011 should probably be '12/01/2011'.

That aside, your proposed solution seems appropriate. Alternatively, if each date for a set of convictions is unique(!) you could also use the date as key (e.g. as UNIX-timestamp, or in YYYYMMDD-format). Retrieving the data would then be as simple as:

```
foreach ($convictions as $date => $description) { ... }
```